# CloufFlare FlexiSSL with Wordpress (Template URL)

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, ssl, cloudflare

I added my website to CloudFlare and enabled Flexi SSL and Installed "SSL Insecure Content Fixer" plugin to fix  insure content.

I have also added page rules to cloudflare to always show https url and everything worked perfect and if i now open my website "hitechcae.com" it goes to "https://hitechcae.com". But now problem begings form here.

All file resources on website appearing using "" do not appear, e.g. if there is image with template url "https://hitechcae.com/wp-content/themes/cae-theme/images/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" it doesn't open, but if i modify URL with adding www to it and make it like "https://www.hitechcae.com/wp-content/themes/cae-theme/images/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" then it works.

My Question is How do i add "WWW" to path when i use template URL function of wordpress.

Regards
Manoj Soni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Settings --> General change your WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) fields to include the www. You may need to run an update on the database as well. To do this I recommend [this tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). You'll replace "//hitechcae.com" with "//www.hitechcae.com".

Make sure that all those settings and what is in the database are the same and you'll be fine.

Comment: I did that, My Wordpress Address and Site Address both already contain WWW but still template url appears without www. This happens only when i changed to https, this site was not https before and it was working perfect.

Comment: Finally Worked, I am using MediaTemple as wordpress hosting so it did not allow me to take effect of Wordpress URL and site URL, i directly went to phpMyAdmin and changed them, and it worked.